# I want to find the numbers of words in a file which contains numbers and special symbols also

Tags: python, regex

I have given a simple text file with no special formatting, just a plain ASCII file, which has special symbols, numbers and words. I need to find the the number of words, letters and special symbols.

Here is my code.

```py
import re
with open("C:/Users/Nikhil/Downloads/stack.txt", "r") as data:
    data = data.read()

words = re.findall(r'\w+', data)
letters = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]', data)
pattern = '[~`@#$%^&*(_)+{}|/\.,<>?-]'
spl_symbols = re.findall(pattern, data)

print(len(words))
print(len(letters))
print(len(spl_symbols))
```

I have used regex to get the output, but the problem is i am unable to get the correct count of words, because `\w+` is matching numbers too. I would like the regex for the `words` variable to be able to exclude numbers 0-9 and underscores. I also would like it to be able to include apostrophes.

Comment: Why not use `words = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+',data)` since you only want words with letters.

Comment: @DarryIG could you let me know why adding a '+' will give me a different result, by the way i have tried your solution but it didnt work. It is counting the word "can't" as two different words....like this 'can' ,'t'. Here is the output when i print the words ```['hey', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'I', 'am', 'can', 't', 'and', 'you', 'Yes', 'I', 'am', 'fine', 'Romeo', 'Mr', 'Garrick']```

Comment: @Nikhilkumar--I posted an answer that shows how to preserve words with apostrophes, such as I'm and didn't, as single words.

Comment: Please be more specific with your question in future. Based on @DarryIG answer, it seems that you do not want 0-9, _ and you also wish to include apostrophes to the regex. I have submitted an edit for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be having trouble with words with apostrophes and numbers.

**Solution**

```
import re

data = "hey, how are you? I'm fine but can't walk.  And you? No, I didn't see Romeo Mr. Garrick"

word_patttern = r"[a-zA-Z]+\'?[a-zA-Z]*"  # changed to allows only
                                          # letters and singe apostrophe

words = re.findall(word_patttern, data)
letters = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]', data)   # unchanged from OP code
pattern = '[~`@#$%^&*(_)+{}|/\.,<>?-]'    # unchanged from OP code
spl_symbols = re.findall(pattern, data)

print(words)
['hey', 'how', 'are', 'you', "I'm", 'fine', 'but', "can't", 'walk', 'And', 'you', 'No', 'I', "didn't", 'see', 'Romeo', 'Mr', 'Garrick']
```

**Explanation**

word_pattern keeps *I'm, can't, didn't* as single words
This is seen by looking at the parts of r"[a-zA-Z]+'?[a-zA-Z]*"

- [a-zA-Z]+  to match one or more letters (comes first in pattern)
- \'?       to match 0 or 1 apostrophe, \ to escape quote (comes second in pattern)
- [a-zA-Z]*  to match 0 or more letters (last part of pattern)

By having [a-zA-Z]+ we don't match Apostrophe by itself (i.e. ' only).  Beside in between letters for compacting words such as "I'm", an apostrophe can come at the end of a word. An example is plural nouns such as "party at the Joneses' house"), so we allow 0 or more letters after the apostrophe.

Comment: @DarryIG that was great, it worked. But i am curious about this piece of code ```+\'?[a-zA-Z]*```, could you please let me know how it works?. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Since it is stated [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_wordchar.asp) that \w consist of a-z, A-Z, 0-9, including the _ (underscore) character. You might want to change your `words` variable to the following:

Option 1:

```
words = re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z_]+", data)
```

Option 2:

```
words = re.findall(r"[^\W0-9]+", data)
```

Option 3 - Apostrophe Support:

```
words = re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z_']+", data)
```

It will include everything `\w` searches for except the numeric 0-9.

Comment: When you say it is not working, could you provide the reason?

Comment: when i use ```\w``` it is counting numbers as strings and when i use ```[a-zA-Z_]+``` it is counting words with apostrophes as two different words

Comment: ```['this', 'is', 'a', 'string', 'with', 'apostrophe', 's'] ```even with `\w` I still get the apostrophes separated.

Answer (score 0):

The regex you are looking for are the following:

```py
import re

words = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+', data)
letters = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]', data)
spl_symbols = re.findall(r'[~`@#$%^&*(_)+{}|/\.,<>?-]', data)
```

On this excerpt of text, it gives:

```
This is an excerpt of text containing special chars like $, _, +. It contains less than 112 words but more than 3.
```

```
words: ['This', 'is', 'an', 'excerpt', 'of', 'text', 'containing', 'special', 'chars', 'like', 'It', 'contains', 'less', 'than', 'words', 'but', 'more', 'than']
letters: ['T', 'h', 'i', 's', 'i', 's', 'a', 'n', 'e', 'x', 'c', 'e', 'r', 'p', 't', 'o', 'f', 't', 'e', 'x', 't', 'c', 'o', 'n', 't', 'a', 'i', 'n', 'i', 'n', 'g', 's', 'p', 'e', 'c', 'i', 'a', 'l', 'c', 'h', 'a', 'r', 's', 'l', 'i', 'k', 'e', 'I', 't', 'c', 'o', 'n', 't', 'a', 'i', 'n', 's', 'l', 'e', 's', 's', 't', 'h', 'a', 'n', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd', 's', 'b', 'u', 't', 'm', 'o', 'r', 'e', 't', 'h', 'a', 'n']
spl_symbols: ['$', ',', '_', ',', '+', '.', '.']
```